# No view found for id for fragment, even that the FrameLayout is a child of the main layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've created code so that Fragment is added dynamically when I tap on a menu button. However I get the error:
No view found for id 0x7f0d009a (tech.glasgowneuro.attysecg:id/fragment_container2) for fragment XYPlotFragment{a75aa2e #0 id=0x7f0d009a}
I've been through all the other posts here and the std answer is that the Frame layout needs to be child of the main layout. I think I've done that right. Still no id is found.

activity_plot_window.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <tech.glasgowneuro.attysecg.InfoView
                android:id="@+id/infoview"
                title="Plot Window"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <tech.glasgowneuro.attysecg.RealtimePlotView
                android:id="@+id/realtimeplotview"
                title="Plot Window"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout><!--    </LinearLayout> -->
```

main JAVA code of the Activity:

```
public class AttysECG extends AppCompatActivity {

...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

....
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plot_window);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
....
}

...

            case R.id.showplot:

                // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
                XYPlotFragment plotFragment = new XYPlotFragment();

                // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container2, plotFragment).commit();
```

The question is why do I get this exception? If I do a findViewById(fragment_container2) then the result is null.
How can I get a valid id for the fragment_container2?
At this point the view is certainly inflated because I trigger this crash long after the app has been started.

Comment: You mean to say your view was inflated properly and was displaying before some action instigated this crash. From what you have mentioned, the issue has nothing to do with the fragment you are trying to put in. The framelayout simply is not there. Can you provide more snapshot of the code where the CASE statement is ?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Android studio created two "activity_plot_window.xml" files. One has the suffix _v21 so that there are two versions for the older APIs and the newer ones. It's explained here:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html
I've added the Framelayout to the _v21 file and now it works. [See the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyq2r.png) It's very easy to oversee when not expanded (just a grey (2)).

Answer (score -1):

You need to find it through FragmentManager:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container2);
```

Comment: It's about adding a fragment to the container and that this won't work. It's not about getting a pointer to a fragment. I want to add the fragment plotFragment to the container. However the fragment manager refuses to do it.